# How can pointer to a type be treated as a pointer to an array of that type

Tags: delphi, pointers

So according to [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_%28Delphi%29) (applies to the same page for XE4 to XE8):

> When a pointer holds the address of another variable, we say that it points to the location of that variable in memory or to the data stored there. **In the case of an array or other structured type, a pointer holds the address of the first element in the structure.**

To me the above sounds exactly like [this](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse15.html):

> Remark: Free Pascal treats pointers much the same way as C does. This means that a pointer to some type can be treated as being an array of this type.
>
> From this point of view, the pointer then points to the zeroeth element of this array.

FPC example:

```
program PointerArray;  
var i : Longint;  
    p : ^Longint;  
    pp : array[0..100] of Longint;  
begin  
  for i := 0 to 100 do pp[i] := i; { Fill array }  
  p := @pp[0];                     { Let p point to pp }  
  for i := 0 to 100 do  
    if p[i]<>pp[i] then  
      WriteLn (’Ohoh, problem !’)  
end.
```

The example obviously doesn't compile and complains about `p` - `Array type required`. I have never seen such shananigans in delphi, but I am very confused by the info from the embarcadero wiki. The wiki itself gives no examples of such use.

Could someone explain to me what is exactly meant by the wiki? And if it is in fact similar to the FPC/C in any way, could someone provide a working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi you have to enable a special compiler mode to be able to treat a pointer as if it were a pointer to an array. That mode is enabled with the [`POINTERMATH`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)) directive like this:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
```

From the documentation:

> Pointer math is simply treating any given typed pointer in some narrow
>   instances as a scaled ordinal where you can perform simple arithmetic
>   operations directly on the pointer variable. It also allows you to
>   treat such a pointer variable as an unbounded array using the array []
>   operator. Notice in the example above that incrementing the index of
>   an array of a type is equivalent to incrementing a pointer to that
>   type. An increment of one bumps the pointer by the size an array
>   element in bytes, not by one byte.
>
> The POINTERMATH directive has a local scope. That is, if you turn this
>   directive ON and do not turn it off in the module, it will remain on
>   only until the end of the module. Also, if you declare a typed pointer
>   with this directive ON, any variable of that type allows scaled
>   pointer arithmetic and array indexing, even after the directive has
>   been turned OFF Similarly, any block of code surrounded by this
>   directive allows arithmetic operations for ANY typed pointers within
>   the block regardless of whether the typed pointer was originally
>   declared with POINTERMATH ON.
>
> This directive affects only typed pointers. Variables of type Pointer
>   do not allow the pointer math features, since type Pointer is
>   effectively pointing to a void element, which is 0 bytes in size.
>   Untyped var or const parameters are not affected because they are not
>   really pointers.

Comment: I knew I would facepalm hard, something just told me that that mode is on by default. My bad. Thanks, will accept asap.

Comment: This feature was introduced with D2009. Probably they set it to false by default to keep some compatibility with older versions.

Comment: It is on for certain types. It has been on for PChar (in $X+ mode) since, IIRC, Borland/Turbo Pascal 7, and is on by default for PByte since the introduction of $POINTERMATH.